# cv2.projectPoints distortion issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv

I'm trying to project some virtual points into image with

```
cv2.projectPoints
```

However I get some distortion whereas I'm passing by zero distortion coefficients.

[image: Distortion]

Here are my parameters :

```
camera_matrix = np.array([[800, 0, 320], [0, 800, 240], [0, 0, 1]], dtype='float32')
dist_coeffs = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='float32')
R_x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, np.cos(zenith), -np.sin(zenith)], [0, np.sin(zenith), np.cos(zenith)]], dtype='float32')
R_y = np.array([[np.cos(azimuth), 0, np.sin(azimuth)], [0, 1, 0], [-np.sin(azimuth), 0, np.cos(azimuth)]], dtype='float32')
R = np.dot(R_y, R_x)

rvec, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R)
t = np.array([0, 0, 10], dtype='float32')

image_points, _ = cv2.projectPoints(object_points, rvec, t, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
```

NB: I'm sure that my .txt file input is without any distrotion according to CloudCompare.

Comment: [mre] please, i.e. input data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.